# JSONP Cross Domain GET request not working across domains

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, cross-domain, jsonp

Ok so I attempting the cross domain ajax webservice call using jsonp to return a list of categories to populate a drop down list and am getting wierd results. I have followed as many examples as possible and have got a jsonp request working on my domain but it doesn't work on other domains.

code below:

```
  function parseJSON(item){
    return   JSON.parse(item, function (key, value) {
                    var type;
                    if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                        type = value.type;
                        if (typeof type === 'string' && typeof window[type] === 'function') {
                            return new (window[type])(value);
                        }
                    }
                    return value;
                });
    };


    function getCategories() {
        var webserviceURL = 'http://www.theprintersinc.co.uk/TPIWS.asmx/getCategories';
        var myData;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: webserviceURL,
            data: { galleryGuid: 1 },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            complete: function (msg) {
                if (msg) {

                var myObject = parseJSON(msg.responseText);
                var myCatList = parseJSON(myObject.d);

                        if (myCatList) {
                             catList = myCatList;
                             setCatDDL();
                        };
                };
                //reset close button
             },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                var err = "err";
            }
         });

    };
```

You can see this working on my domain at http://www.theprintersinc.co.uk/stackHelp.html
However when I try and run this code from a simple html file on my pc or another server it doesn't work. I just get a syntax error from jbug.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated in advance!

Nick

Comment: the response is not JSONP

Comment: On my domain it at least fires and returns a parsable response, as soon as it is on a different domain it displays syntax errors.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions why this may be? Let me knowIf you need to see the webservice...

Comment: your webservice must wrap the JSON in a function-call. The name of the function must be identically to the `callback`-parameter passed to the webservice. The result should look like `jQuery1234567({"foo":"bar"});` , then the response is JSONP

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert, however you can take into consideration what is specified in the jquery documentation about the "same origin policy" restriction: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

"Additional Notes:
Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions."

To use JSONP, you should add callback=? to your URL.
In the same jquery document, there is an example.